# other View(s) dependency?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

[image: See the image]

I have view like the image and ViewModel have commands to handle the button (1,2,3,4) clicks. In work area allow the user to give inputs. Depending upon the input users are allowed click the button;

Each Button leads one new Window(View with ViewModel; whose model will be taken from the inputs). The new window have its own logic to showing the data depending upon the model injected to the ViewModel.

As per the MVVM standards, where do I specify the respective View and ViewModels for the each Button? (In View / View model).
How can I specify the same?

Comment: You have to use PRISM to define region for your working area, then load module/view depending upon you requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have red some information about your reply. But is there any other direct way (instead of using Prism/MVVM Light)? Because we have already build the application. It is not so easy now to convert all the coding.

Comment: Are the views windows you show on top of the view you showed here (Window.Show() or Window.ShowDialog()) or are the views shown in the workarea?

Comment: Actual plan is to show as new window with ShowDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Basically ViewModel is a link between View and Model, so each combination of View and Model should have a separate ViewModel (if valid).

In my experience in most cases we are dealing with two kinds of Views:

1. **small views** such as icons, advanced buttons and so on (which are more isolated and more likely to have no reference to their parents so they are easy to manage and to be generalized)
2. **large views** such as windows, panels (which have a lot of children and are more likely to be changed later)

For small views common ViewModels can be used for multiple Views. but as for large Views (considering possible changes in the future) it's better not to use a single shared ViewModel. however it's helpful to use a base ViewModel class to implement some shared functionality (if any).

So keeping that in mind and focusing to stay standard, I suggest:

- `ViewModels for secondary windows`: (according to the question I think you need 4) Each have their independent functionality (you can derive them all from a BaseWindowVm).best practice here would be not to let them know about their parent (`MainWindowVm`) and just to set their event handlers when they are instantiated. This way you can avoid code coupling.
- `MainWindowVm`: consists of 4 commands and some other inputs. Each command does these steps:

  1. instantiates a View
  2. instantiates a `ViewModel for secondary window` based on input
  3. set Vm's event handlers
  4. assign the Vm to DataContext of the View
  5. add the Vm to some list in `MainWindowVm` (If you want to keep track of these windows)
  6. ShowDialog()

The most important part is that since ViewModels communicate with each other, linking Views with each other only make it more complicated and more difficult to manage. so Views are like islands with bindings to their ViewModels and everything else is up to ViewModels.